# how to use k-fold cross validation and Weighted Random Sampler together?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, cross-validation, dataloader

I'm trying to train my classification model(3 classes) using PyTorch (data_loader)
so my first problem was that the data was not balanced so I used **Weighted Random Sampler** :

```
  class_weights = [5,1,1] 

  sample_weights = [0] * len(ds)

  for idx in enumerate(ds):
      class_weight = class_weights[idx[1]['targets']]
      sample_weights[idx[0]] = class_weight

  sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(sample_weights, num_samples=
                                    len(sample_weights), replacement=True)
  DataLoader( ds, batch_size=batch_size,  sampler=sampler, num_workers=2 )
```

but now I have another problem which is the *overfitting* so I want to use **K-fold cross-validation**

can someone help me cus I really don't know how to do it!?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what should i add 